# Loop not working properly and key output wrong

Tags: python, json, loops, csv, keyerror

Ok, I'm going to start showing my code:

```
import requests
import json
import csv
import pandas as pd

with open('AcoesURLJsonCompleta.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    urlreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for obj_id in urlreader:

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}
jsonData = requests.get(row, headers=headers).json()

mapper = (
    ('Ticker', 'ric'),
    ('Beta', 'beta'),
    ('DY', 'current_dividend_yield_ttm'),
    ('VOL', 'share_volume_3m'),
    ('P/L', 'pe_normalized_annual'),
    ('Cresc5A', 'eps_growth_5y'),
    ('LPA', 'eps_normalized_annual'),
    ('VPA', 'book_value_share_quarterly'),
    ('LAST', 'last')
)

data = {}
for dataKey, jsonDataKey in mapper: 
    d = jsonData.get(jsonDataKey, '') 
    try:
        flt_d = float(d)
    except ValueError:
        d = ''
    finally:
        data[dataKey] = [d]

table = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Ticker', 'Beta', 'DY', 'VOL', 'P/L', 'Cresc5A', 'LPA', 'VPA', 'Last'])
table.index = table.index + 1
table.to_csv('CompleteData.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
print(table)
```

Ok so lets get started with:

1. My first loop `for rows in Urls` is correct? I want to loop through my Urls stored in my CSV file, but I don't know if I'm using split and strip correctly.
2. My json requests are ok?
3. If any of that `jsonData` requests return a NaN or Null or doesn't find anything, how should I put that on my code so it will skip to the other URL and append "" (nothing) when this happens?

The output for this entire code is `line 25, in <module>
    Beta = jsonData['beta']
KeyError: 'beta'`

Thank you

Comment: Please double check the indentation of your code

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: @alec_djinn Please, could show me what part of indentation is wrong? I'm new in Python and can't figure it out.

Comment: @quamrana I've put the all outcome of this code, is that what you meant?

Comment: That will do. This means the returned data has no key ‘beta’. What should happen in those cases?

Comment: @quamrana That was my number 3 - If any of that jsonData requests return a NaN or Null or doesn't find anything, how should I put that on my code so it will skip to the other URL and append.whateverkey "" (nothing) when this happens? Remember, this will probably happen in more than one URL in my CSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Code**

I have taken the few lines of URL you have supplied and ran the following code against it and printed out the results. This version uses multiple threads to fetch the URLs and a `requests` Session. This greatly speeds up processing.

There is a constant near the top of the code, `NUMBER_OF_CONCURRENT_URL_REQUESTS`, that determines the number of concurrent URL get requests that will be made. I have tried various numbers from 8 to 30. This is what I have learned (or appears to be true):

1. Regardless of of the setting for `NUMBER_OF_CONCURRENT_URL_REQUESTS`, if you run the program twice quickly in succession, you get the same results. It would appear that the server is caching request results for some period of time.
2. However, if you wait long enough so that the cache does not come into play, you get different results, i.e. different errors as far as data being missing. Why this is I cannot say.
3. The larger the value of `NUMBER_OF_CONCURRENT_URL_REQUESTS`, the faster the program runs. There may be some value that is so large that the server might get upset and think that you are trying to commit a denial of service attack. I don't see any reason to make this value larger than 30.
4. Is there a correlation between the larger the value of `NUMBER_OF_CONCURRENT_URL_REQUESTS` and the likelihood of having missing data? I cannot say for certain, **but that appears to be the case, and it makes no sense to me.** You can try different values and see for yourself one way or another.

The code:

```
import csv, requests, pandas as pd
from decimal import Decimal, DecimalException
from collections import defaultdict
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from functools import partial
from time import sleep

NUMBER_OF_CONCURRENT_URL_REQUESTS = 8

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}

def request_getter(session, url):
    ric = url.split('/')[-1] # in case results does not contain 'ric' key
    for t in (0, 1000, 2000, 4000, 4000):
        if t:
            sleep(t)
            print(f"Retrying request '{ric}' ...", flush=True)
        data = session.get(url, headers=headers).json()
        if 'retry' not in data:
            break
    return ric, data


mapper = (
    ('Ticker', 'ric'),
    ('Beta', 'beta'),
    ('DY', 'current_dividend_yield_ttm'),
    ('VOL', 'share_volume_3m'),
    ('P/L', 'pe_normalized_annual'),
    ('Cresc5A', 'eps_growth_5y'),
    ('LPA', 'eps_normalized_annual'),
    ('VPA', 'book_value_share_quarterly'),
    ('LAST', 'last')
)

data = defaultdict(list)
with open('AcoesURLJsonCompleta.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    urlreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    # set max_workers to # cpu processors you have and use a requests Session for even more perofrmance
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=NUMBER_OF_CONCURRENT_URL_REQUESTS) as executor, requests.Session() as session:
        request_getter_with_session = partial(request_getter, session)
        for ric, results in executor.map(request_getter_with_session, (row[0] for row in urlreader)):
            if 'market_data' not in results:
                print(f"Missing 'market_data' key for request '{ric}'", flush=True)
                for k, v in results.items():
                    print(f'    {repr(k)} -> {repr(v)}', flush=True)
                print(flush=True)
                continue
            market_data = results['market_data']
            if 'ric' not in market_data:
                # see if any of the mapper keys are present:
                found = False
                for _, jsonDataKey in mapper:
                    if jsonDataKey in market_data:
                        found = True
                        break
                if not found:
                    print(f"Request '{ric}' has nothing recognizable in market_data:", flush=True)
                    for k, v in market_data.items():
                        print(f'    {repr(k)} -> {repr(v)}', flush=True)
                    print(flush=True)
                    continue
                # We have at least one data value present
                print(f"Results missing 'ric' key; inferring 'ric' value '{ric}' from request URL.", flush=True)
                market_data['ric'] = ric
            for dataKey, jsonDataKey in mapper: # for example, 'Ticker', 'ric'
                d = market_data.get(jsonDataKey)
                if d is None:
                    print(f"Data missing for request = '{ric}', key = '{jsonDataKey}'", flush=True)
                    d = '' if jsonDataKey == 'ric' else Decimal('NaN')
                else:
                    try:
                        if jsonDataKey != 'ric': d = Decimal(d)
                    except DecimalException:
                        print(f"Bad value for '{jsonDataKey}': {repr(d)}", flush=True)
                        d = Decimal('NaN') # Decimal class has it's own version
                data[dataKey].append(d) # add to data

table = pd.DataFrame(data)
table.index = table.index + 1
table.to_csv('CompleteData.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
print(table)
"""
# to read back table:
table2 = pd.read_csv('CompleteData.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', converters={
    'Ticker': str,
    'Beta': Decimal,
    'DY': Decimal,
    'VOL': Decimal,
    'P/L': Decimal,
    'Cresc5A': Decimal,
    'LPA': Decimal,
    'VPA': Decimal,
    'LAST': Decimal
})
print(table2)
"""
```

Prints:

```
Missing 'market_data' key for request CPLE6.sa
status -> {}
message -> service returned code:
rcom_service_message -> None

Missing 'market_data' key for request EQMA3B.sa
status -> {}
message -> service returned code:
rcom_service_message -> None

Data missing for ric GNDI3.sa, key beta
Data missing for ric GNDI3.sa, key current_dividend_yield_ttm
Data missing for ric GNDI3.sa, key share_volume_3m
Data missing for ric GNDI3.sa, key pe_normalized_annual
Data missing for ric GNDI3.sa, key eps_growth_5y
Data missing for ric GNDI3.sa, key eps_normalized_annual
Data missing for ric GNDI3.sa, key book_value_share_quarterly
Missing 'market_data' key for request MDNE3.sa
status -> {}
message -> service returned code:
rcom_service_message -> None

Missing 'market_data' key for request MMXM11.sa
status -> {}
message -> service returned code:
rcom_service_message -> None

Missing 'market_data' key for request PCAR3.sa
status -> {}
message -> service returned code:
rcom_service_message -> None

Results missing ric key; inferring ric value from request URL.
Data missing for ric RAIL3.sa, key last
Results missing ric key; inferring ric value from request URL.
Data missing for ric SANB4.sa, key last
Missing 'market_data' key for request TIMP3.sa
status -> {}
message -> service returned code:
rcom_service_message -> None

Missing 'market_data' key for request VIVT3.sa
status -> {}
message -> service returned code:
rcom_service_message -> None

       Ticker     Beta        DY        VOL           P/L       Cresc5A       LPA       VPA       LAST
1    AALR3.sa  1.04339   0.80591   11.00223      26.44449  -99999.99000   0.39668  10.83966  10.490000
2    ABCB4.sa  1.20526   7.34780   18.61900       5.78866       5.42894   2.46862  18.87782  14.290000
3    ABEV3.sa  0.46311   4.32628  688.21043      15.04597      -0.71223   0.75369   3.89563  11.340000
4    ADHM3.sa  1.69780   0.00000    2.36460  -99999.99000  -99999.99000  -0.65331  -2.61497   2.480000
5    AGRO3.sa  0.35568   4.53332    2.54323      41.17127  -99999.99000   0.49792  17.47838  20.500000
..        ...      ...       ...        ...           ...           ...       ...       ...        ...
255  WEGE3.sa  0.50580   1.02429  165.72543      50.11481      17.06485   0.79697   4.59658  39.940000
256  WHRL3.sa  0.59263   8.86991    1.24990      12.72584       0.65648   0.50920   2.00868   6.700000
257  WHRL4.sa  0.59263   8.86991    1.24990      12.72584       0.65648   0.50920   2.00868   6.480000
258  WIZS3.sa  0.76719  12.18673   19.00407       6.67135      21.23109   1.36704   1.16978   9.120000
259  YDUQ3.sa  1.42218   1.68099   94.00410      13.83419       9.13751   2.19384  10.31845  30.350000

[259 rows x 9 columns]
```

Next run:

```
Missing 'market_data' key for request CPLE6.sa
status -> {}
message -> service returned code:
rcom_service_message -> None

Missing 'market_data' key for request EQMA3B.sa
status -> {}
message -> service returned code:
rcom_service_message -> None

Missing 'market_data' key for request MDNE3.sa
status -> {}
message -> service returned code:
rcom_service_message -> None

Missing 'market_data' key for request MMXM11.sa
status -> {}
message -> service returned code:
rcom_service_message -> None

Missing 'market_data' key for request PCAR3.sa
status -> {}
message -> service returned code:
rcom_service_message -> None

Missing 'market_data' key for request TIMP3.sa
status -> {}
message -> service returned code:
rcom_service_message -> None

Missing 'market_data' key for request VIVT3.sa
status -> {}
message -> service returned code:
rcom_service_message -> None

       Ticker     Beta        DY        VOL           P/L       Cresc5A       LPA       VPA       LAST
1    AALR3.sa  1.04339   0.80591   11.00223      26.44449  -99999.99000   0.39668  10.83966  10.490000
2    ABCB4.sa  1.20526   7.34780   18.61900       5.78866       5.42894   2.46862  18.87782  14.290000
3    ABEV3.sa  0.46311   4.32628  688.21043      15.04597      -0.71223   0.75369   3.89563  11.340000
4    ADHM3.sa  1.69780   0.00000    2.36460  -99999.99000  -99999.99000  -0.65331  -2.61497   2.480000
5    AGRO3.sa  0.35568   4.53332    2.54323      41.17127  -99999.99000   0.49792  17.47838  20.500000
..        ...      ...       ...        ...           ...           ...       ...       ...        ...
255  WEGE3.sa  0.50580   1.02429  165.72543      50.11481      17.06485   0.79697   4.59658  39.940000
256  WHRL3.sa  0.59263   8.86991    1.24990      12.72584       0.65648   0.50920   2.00868   6.700000
257  WHRL4.sa  0.59263   8.86991    1.24990      12.72584       0.65648   0.50920   2.00868   6.480000
258  WIZS3.sa  0.76719  12.18673   19.00407       6.67135      21.23109   1.36704   1.16978   9.120000
259  YDUQ3.sa  1.42218   1.68099   94.00410      13.83419       9.13751   2.19384  10.31845  30.350000

[259 rows x 9 columns]
```

**Discussion**

The code has been made more complex by using threads and a requests Session object, but the complexity is necessary to greatly reduce the running time of the program.

To understand the code, you need to understand the `ThreadPoolExecutor`, the `map` function (`ThreadPoolExcecutor.map` method is a variation on this that assigns a thread to execute the function call) and `functools.partial`, which is required since `map` expects that its function argument is a function that takes a single argument but we need to call `request_getter` with two arguments, a `requests` Session object, which never varies, and a URL. `partial` allows us to transform a function that takes two arguments into a function that takes one argument with the other argument automatically provided. For example:

```
def foo(x, y):
    return x + y

def foo7(y):
    return partial(foo, 7) # the first argument to foo now will always be 7

foo7(9) # equivalent to foo(7, 9)
```

**To read back csv file:**

```
from decimal import Decimal
import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_csv('CompleteData.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', converters={
    'Ticker': str,
    'Beta': Decimal,
    'DY': Decimal,
    'VOL': Decimal,
    'P/L': Decimal,
    'Cresc5A': Decimal,
    'LPA': Decimal,
    'VPA': Decimal,
    'LAST': Decimal    
})
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213050/discussion-on-answer-by-booboo-loop-not-working-properly-and-key-output-wrong).

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to encapsulate the idea of requirement 3 in its own function:

```
def transfer(src, dest, src_name, dest_name):
    try:
        value = src[src_name]
    except KeyError:
        return
    try:
        value = float(value)
    except TypeError:
        return
    dest[dest_name].append(value)

# Sample call:
transfer(jsonData, data, 'ric', 'Ticker')
```

This eliminates errors due to missing values and the json `null`. Since json has no concept of `NaN`, I can't handle it here.

Comment: Hi @quamrana this is the output: `line 35, in <module>
    transfer(jsonData, data, 'ric', 'Ticker') line 30, in transfer
    value = float(value)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'AALR3.SA,\n'` that AALR3.SA is a stock ticker. My CSV doesn't have that \n in the end.

Comment: Also I deleted those `append` and did `transfer` as you said.

Comment: Given that the `'ric'` element gives you `'AALR3.SA,\n'`, which part is the 'Ticker' and how does this compare to other values? You probably need a very reliable conversion.

Comment: The ticker is `AALR3.SA`. What should I do?

Comment: Write a new question on stackoverflow